# Hieraerchical documents in Solr

Tags: solr, facet

I have to index and search documents in Solr. I also need filtering, faceting and pagination features. My (simplified) ideal document structure is the following:

```xml
<doc>
  <id>1</id>
  <title>A title</title>
  <description>A description...</description>
  <category>speech</category>
  <sentences>
    <sentence>
      <n>1</n>
      <from>00:00:00</from>
      <to>00:00:10</to>
      <tag>presentation</tag>
      <transcript>Hello, my name is Alberto!</transcript>
    </sentence>
    <sentence>
      <n>2</n>
      <from>00:00:10</from>
      <to>00:00:15</to>
      <tag>talk</tag>
      <transcript>and blah blah blah</transcript>
    </sentence>
  </sentences>
</doc>
```

A document can have many sentences. Each sentence can have multiple tags.

I would like to perform search on `title`, `description` and `transcript`, filter on `tag` (sentence level) and `category` (root level), and get faceting on `category` and `tag`.

Some of the requirements are:

- faceting should return the numbers based on documents and not sentences
- filteting should not give false positive results. For example if I search for `q=text:"Alberto&fq=tag:presentation`, document 1 should be returned. But if I search for `q=text:blah&fq=tag:presentation`, nothing should be returned.

The only viable solution I have found is to use **grouping** (`group=true&group.facet=true`) and to **flat the document structure**. The problem here is that I have to copy faceting fields (for example `category`) in every document (also the ones that identify a sentence), otherwise faceting doesn't work correctly.

Also re-indexing the ideal document requires to delete every sentence of the document, and then re-index the group of document.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Would having two collections work? One flat with documents+sentencetags+sentencetranscript, and one with just sentences? That way you can facet on documents, but also query a separate collection to find the sentences that matched for that document (by having a docid on the sentence document). Yes, it would require submitting two updates - but reindexing should be as easy as possible from your appcode anyway, and you can deleteByQuery based on docid from sentence collection.

Comment: @MatsLindh I think it would return false positives as in `q=text:blah&fq=tag:presentation`. There is no sentence containing `blah` tagged as `presentation`, but since in your solution tags are put together at document level, it would match.

Comment: Good point! How many tags are we talking about? You could use the tag as the field name in those cases, and search tag_presentation:blah (or search against the sentence collection and get the unique docids to search the doc collection)

Comment: Thank you. I haven't fully understood the tag_presentation trick, but however this is just an example. I have many fields like tag and each one can have many values.
The two phase search, instead, could perform very bad with pagination.